# if else condition with Knockout

Tags: knockout.js, knockout-mvc

I'm very new at Knockout.
I have a problem, how can I use if/else with Knockout.

For example like this

```
<ul class="list-group" data-bind="foreach: users">
    <li class="list-group-item" data-bind="click : setasUser">
        <i class="fa fa-circle text-success"></i> <span data-bind="text: name"></span>
    </li>
</ul>
```

I want to have a non-clikable item if `username == x`

How can I do this?

Comment: Check out the [if binding](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/if-binding.html)

Comment: You should be checking the `enable` binding http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/enable-binding.html

Answer (score 5):

unfortunately knockout does not have if else. however it does have an if binding and a ifnot binding.

here is a fiddle. http://jsfiddle.net/LkqTU/35843/

```
<ul class="list-group" data-bind="foreach: users">
<!-- ko ifnot: username() === 'x' -->
    <li class="list-group-item" data-bind="click : $parent.setasUser">
        <i class="fa fa-circle text-success"></i> <span data-bind="text: name"></span>
    </li>
  <!-- /ko -->
  <!-- ko if: username() === 'x' -->
  <li class="list-group-item" data-bind="text: name"> </li>
   <!-- /ko -->
</ul>
```

Answer (score 2):

Simply you can set the click event function on based on your condition like below

```
<ul class="list-group" data-bind="foreach: users">
    <li class="list-group-item" data-bind="click : username !== x ? setasUser: null">
        <i class="fa fa-circle text-success"></i> <span data-bind="text: name"></span>
    </li>
</ul>
```